# Column name not found when i use trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a trigger when I insert a specific column value to print message but when I execute the following code, I get an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure company_trigger_insert, Line 6
>   Invalid column name 'company_id'.

Here is my trigger:

```
create trigger company_trigger_insert on company
after Insert
as
begin
    IF company_id = 1
    BEGIN
        print 'one';
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        print 'anything';
    END
end
```

and I'll be thankful if anyone could help me.

Although I use `company_id` as a primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in triggers use **inserted** or **deleted** to access the modifying data
and also **IF company_id = 1** in your code is ambiguous.

```
create trigger company_trigger_insert on company
 after Insert
 as
 begin
 IF (select top 1 inserted.company_id from inserted)= 1
  BEGIN
      print 'INSERTING';
  END
  ELSE
  BEGIN
     print 'delete';
  END
end
```

Comment: new error appear


Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure company_trigger_insert, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "inserted.company_id" could not be bound.

Comment: Sorry, I was in hurry, I corrected it, can you try it again?

Comment: great, you know, it depends on your scenario to choose **instead of** or **after**